# How to exclude specific menu item from https? (wrapper menu item)

Tags: menu-item, ssl, https, wrapper

I have site with https. I have a few wrappers menu items that load forms from another site. These sites are not mine and they do not use ssl.
Before I switch to https, everything was loading normally, but after enabling https, the forms are getting blocked by the browsers, warning me about insecure content.

Question: is it possible to exclude these specific pages from https and load them through http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select if you want a specific menu item to be secured with SSL or not. Inside your wrapper menu item, go to the Metadata Tab and you will find the "Secure" field option. You can set it to off.

Comment: Thank you very much. I spend too much time try to make it through htaccess.

Comment: @Murad:: You are welcome, I m glad if I helped. If your question is answered, then please accept my post as the answer to your issue.